# Getting google maps to stay below sticky nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

Working on a website and it involves a sticky.js sticky nav and a google map. I added the map and the sticky nav. Everything operates pretty smoothly but the google map does not interact the same with the sticky nav. As I scroll up or down the nav falls behind the google map rather than covering over it as it does with every other element on the page. So to further paint a picture of the issue: The nav sticks to the top of the page as I scroll around. It covers anything that it passes over, however the google map covers it up and it creates a poor experience. I hope this is enough info to get a helpful answer. Thanks everyone.

Comment: We need some kind of html and css that you are using. In this case you have problem with the z-index in the css. Try to add z-index: 1 to the google maps container

Comment: No one can reproduce your issue if you do not provide any code example!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute,
>   position:relative, or position:fixed).

So for example if the navbar has a z-index of 2 and the map of 1 the navbar will always be over the map.

It is written as

```
    .sticky_nav{
         z-index:2;
    }
```

Comment: No not yet. I appreciate your input though. I am going to take another swing at this closer to my deadline. Moved onto different parts of the project.

Answer (score 0):

add proparty z-index to your sticky-nav class
like your sticky nav class="sticky_nav"

So inside your css file put that class

```
     .sticky_nav{
      z-index=2010;
      }
```

I put that value 2010 because I didn't know what is actually google map z-index value. or there is some other issue ..
or provide your site link ..let us check 
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input. I figured it out by accident while I was working on another issue with the sticky nav. The sticky.js jquery plugin has some defaults set and one of them was setting the z-index to auto. I was able to change the z-index to 2 and this solved my problem. Thank you all for your assistance.